# How to store translations in nosql DB with minimal duplication?

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I got this schema in DynamoDB

```
{
"timestamp" : "",
"fruit" : {
    "name" : "orange",
    "translations" : [
        { 
            "en-GB" : "orange" 
        },
        {
            "sv-SE" : "apelsin"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

I need to store translations for objects in a DynamoDB database, to be able to query them efficiently. E.g. my query has to be something like "give me all objects where translations array contains "

The problem is, is this a really dumb idea? There are 6500 languages out there, and this means I will be forcing all entries to each contain an array with thousands of properties with 99% of them empty string values. What's a better approach? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your willing to let DynamoDB do a table scan to get your results, I think your using the wrong tool.  Consider streaming your transactions to AWS ElasticSearch via something like Firehose.  Firehose will give you a lot of nice to haves and can help you rotate transaction indexes.  ElasticSearch should able to store that structure and run your query.

If you don't go that route, then at least consider dropping the language code in your structure if your not actually using it.  Just make an array of the unique spellings of your fruit.  This is the kind of query I might try to do with multiple queries instead of a single one; Go from the spelling of the fruit name to a fruit UUID which you can then query against.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather save it as.

```
{
"primaryKey" : "orange",
"SecondaryKey": "en-GB"
"timestamp" : "",
"Metadata" : {
    "name" : "orange",

}
```

And create a secondary-index with SecondaryKey as PK and primaryKey as SK.

By Doing this you can query

1. Get me orange in en-GB.
2. What all keys existing in en-GB

---

If you are updating multiple item at once. You can create 1 object like this

```
{
"KeyName" : "orange",
"SecondaryKey": "master"
"timestamp" : "",
"fruit" : {
    "name" : "orange",
    "translations" : [
        { 
            "en-GB" : "orange" 
        },
        {
            "sv-SE" : "apelsin"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

And create a lambda function who denormalises the above object and creates multiple entities in dynamodb. But you will have to take create of deleting the elements as well. If in the new object some language is not there.

Comment: DynamoDB has a size limitation of 10GB on your partition.  If you setup a partition key on the word orange, then you'll only be able to store 10GB worth of transactions.  Maybe this is ok, maybe this isn't.  But it certainly an important detail to keep in mind.  Same goes for when you create a GSI.  Given enough time and transactions you might find yourself in a bad place with this schema.